# Google Apps for a Mailer for my Website SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, google-apps

I'm just wondering what people use for their websites in regards to a mailing service. I'm looking into when it is best to use SMTP vs when it is best to use a restful API mailing system.

At this point in time I had been using SMTP, but has been causing a bit of trouble.

The mailing system is just basic notification and event emails. (Change password, enquiry, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google apps is not ment to be used for transactional emails and you will probably run into problems at some point when setting this up. It will also require more work than using a service that more suites the need for sending transactional emails.

Have a look at [Mailgun](http://mailgun.com) and [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com) that offers simple api integrations for fast setup of transactional emails for most languages.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your answer. That basically is what I was looking for. I was not sure the benefits of actually implementing the http vs the smtp. :)